# Can Gourmet still run on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python-2.7, 20.04

I am a Gourmet user for my cooking recipes, I found no better alternative on Ubuntu for that. Gnome Recipes is attractive and promising, but dev is not very active from what I can see, and it lacks import function which is mandatory to me, as I have a huge list of my own recipes.

I checked in a VM to install Gourmet on Ubuntu 20.04 with no luck : I can install Python 2.7 (no more installed by default), I can find a Gourmet .deb package (removed from store), but when tying to install (with GDebi) I have that error : `Dependency error not satisfied with python-gtk2 (>= 2.22.0)`

And python-gtk2 package is no more available. So I am stuck here !

Comment: We are working on the new version of Gourmet which will be `python3` compatible. I hope it will be distributed via original channels. Any contribution is highly appreciated!: https://github.com/kirienko/gourmet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation is still possible, but you have to download packages manually from previous Ubuntu releases with commands below:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/gourmet
cd ~/Downloads/gourmet

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gourmet/gourmet_0.17.4-7_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-reportlab/python-reportlab_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/elib.intl/python-elib.intl_0.0.3~git20110809-5_all.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-reportlab/python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtkspellcheck/python-gtkspellcheck_4.0.5-1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pyenchant/python-enchant_2.0.0-1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-mechanize/python-mechanize_0.2.5-3_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/beautifulsoup/python-beautifulsoup_3.2.1-1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04 install python-cairo

```
sudo apt install python-cairo
```

> Configurando python-cairo:amd64 (1.16.2-2ubuntu2)... 
>   Configurando python-gtk2 (2.24.0-6)...